# Add "Please Wait" popup on advanced search page

Tags: 2010, advanced-search

As some of my searches take a while, I wanted to put up some sort of message that the search is running.  [This site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/63b79fca-0f9b-428e-ae62-f30a5eb13596/sharepoint-2013-search-results-please-wait-dialog-box?forum=sharepointgeneral): has info on adding such a thing in 2013, but I'd have thought the message would have to be on the advanced search page, not the results page.

Has anyone seen such a solution for 2010?